# Como faço para colocar um ícone de olho que pode revelar ou ocultar senha dentro do input?

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para **substituir o botão de `Ver ou ocultar senha` por um olho dentro do input de Senha (no final da lateral direita)**? Eu não sou muito bom em front-end e lembrando que o atributo `title` não deve ser alterado nem no `<input>` e nem no ícone do olho.

```js
function viewSenha(){
   var tipo = document.getElementById("senha")
   if (tipo.type == "password") {
    tipo.type = "text";
   }else{
    tipo.type = "password";
   }
  }
```

```html
<p> Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" title="Campo para inserir a senha de login do funcionário" size="30" maxlength="32" required=""> <button type="button" title="Ver ou ocultar senha" onclick="viewSenha()"> Ver ou ocultar senha </button> </p>
```

Comment: use css, pode usar a propriedade `background` ou `background-image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou deixar um exemplo bem simples só complementando a resposta do **@hugocsl**, utilizando ícones do `font-awesome` implementando uma troca de ícones conforme o seu clique:

```js
var tipo = document.getElementById('senha')

document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(tipo.value) {
    tipo.type == 'password' ? tipo.type = 'text' : tipo.type = 'password';
    tipo.focus()
    document.getElementById('pass').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
})

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(tipo.value) {
    tipo.type == 'text' ? tipo.type = 'password' : tipo.type = 'text';
    tipo.focus()
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pass').style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
})
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

i {
  margin-left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p> Senha:
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" title="Campo para inserir a senha de login do funcionário" size="30" maxlength="32" required="">
  <i class="fa fa-eye" id="text"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="pass"></i>
</p>
```

**OBS :** No meu exemplo o Css foi só para fazer o exemplo mesmo, não sei se é o melhor aí para o seu caso.
**OBS :** Se quiser utilizar imagens no lugar a lógica do javascript seria a mesma.

Comment: Seu código ficou interessante por causa da mudança de ícone, fiz do jeito que você fez só que não retorna nada.

Comment: Como assim não retorna nada?

Comment: Não retorna o ícone.

Comment: Tem que ver se importou os ícones corretamente do font-awesome e a versão do font-awesome, assim também as classes dos ícones. Dependendo da versão usa **fas fa-...** ou **fa fa-...**

Comment: Eu importei o link do arquivo CSS no meu arquivo CSS.

Comment: Consegui resolver, mais aparentemente quando fui fazer isso em um arquivo de atualização onde possui uma requisição de dados em JSON **não funciona**, os caracteres da senha ficam apenas ocultos.

Comment: Legal que conseguiu, aí nesse caso só vendo os arquivos mesmo pra saber.

Comment: Acho que não vou mais fazer o que disse anteriormente, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tem uma opção simples, usando uma `img` dentro do `btn`, simples assim...

Eu dei um `all: unset` para limpar todo os estilos padrão do botão  do `user-agent` e coloquei dentro dela a imagem, já que dentro de um `<button>` é permitido [Flow Content (tag `<img>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)

O `padding` que coloquei no `input` é para o texto não ir até o final, assim ficando encoberto, pois o `btn` estaria por cima... Deixei o comentário no CSS abaixo.

```js
function viewSenha(){
  var tipo = document.getElementById("senha")
  if (tipo.type == "password") {
    tipo.type = "text";
  }else{
    tipo.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```css
#senha {
  /* esse valor deve ser o mesmo do margin left aplicado no btn abaixo */
  padding-right: 30px; 
}
#senha + button,
#senha + button:hover,
#senha + button:focus {
  all: unset;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p> Senha: 
  <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" title="Campo para inserir a senha de login do funcionário" size="30" maxlength="32" required=""> 
  <button type="button" title="Ver ou ocultar senha" onclick="viewSenha()">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/16/16">
  </button> 
</p>
```